# Build UpdateCommand for DataAdapter with some parsing applied to the SourceColumn?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

At first, I'll show the standard way to build a custom `UpdateCommand` for a `DataAdapter` (used commonly when the Select has many tables involved and we can't use `CommandBuilder` to build all the commands automatically for a `DataAdapter`).

Here is code for my DataAdapter:

```
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name FROM MyTable", myConnection);
```

Here is code for building a standard `UpdateCommand` for `myAdapter`. The example above involves only 1 single table, however, that's just for simple and demonstrative purpose.

```
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET ID=@id,Name=@name WHERE ID=@id2", myConnection);
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.VarChar).SourceColumn = "ID";
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.VarChar).SourceColumn = "Name";
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("id2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "ID").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
```

The problem is I don't want to bind the the `Parameter` to a `SourceColumn` exactly. I want to change the value from `SourceColumn` a little before the values are passed to the corresponding Parameter. For example, my ID column contains all the values like 1,2,3,4,... I would like to append some string (e.g: 000, 001, A, B, C, ...) before it and pass this custom `SourceColumn` to my Parameter. With the code above, the passed values are exactly what the `SourceColumn` ID has: 1,2,3,4... and what I want is for example: C1,C2,C3,C4,...

That's is some kind of parsing value using some middle layer, I would like to know if this is possible. Parsing the value of `SourceColumn` outside is OK however there is some case I have to parse it right when building the `UpdateCommand` for my Adapter. Here is a case:

I have a `DataGridView` which has a column of Gender, this column is of type `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with 2 items: Male and Female. The underlying datasource should have a corresponding Gender column and the values should be "Male" and "Female", all the unmatched values (not contained in the Items list of the `ComboBoxColumn`) won't make the ComboBoxCell display the value correctly. I've tried `CellFormating` and `CellPainting` but it didn't work. `CellPainting` is too complex and `CellFormating` didn't work at all. In fact, I'm not using a standard .NET `DataGridView`, I'm using a custom `DataGridView` (also inherits from the standard `DataGridView`). All I've done to this `DataGridView` didn't work. The only solution is to prepare all the underlying values to include only "Male" and "Female". However I designed my `Gender` column as a boolean/bit column. Here is the SELECT command:

```
SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, CASE WHEN Gender = 1 THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END Gender FROM MyTable", myConnection);
```

The `Gender` column now is type of varchar or text and not a boolean/bit as I did before. But the `Gender` column in the original table is type of bit. How can I build my `UpdateCommand` for the SELECT command above? A solution is include a hidden `Gender` column and use this column for the SourceColumn to build the UpdateCommand, the visible `Gender` is just for displaying. This is however a little much more work to do. If I could do some kind of Custom `SourceColumn`, it would be better to use.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are going into the wrong direction. Instead of adjusting your data according to the view, do it the other way round: Make your data look as you want it to. To display lookup values (i.e. gender), use the `CellFormatting` event (for example).

Comment: @alzaimar alzaimar, Haven't you read my question carefully? I'm not a newbie without knowing about CellFormating, I've done a lot of CellFormating to display the text as I want, but the case is the ComboBoxColumn requires the underlying data values to be in the Items list. I'm not sure if CellFormating works with a standard DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but I'm working with a custom comboBoxcolumn called DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn (from DotNetBar) and I've tried with CellFormating, it didn't work at all. That's why I need another solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ KingKing. If I create a Combobox column, I have two members: `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. Does your 'ComboBoxExColumn' has similar properties? Doesn't that solve your problem in displaying what you want to see and saving what you need?

Comment: ComboBoxExColumn has all the properties the standard ComboBoxColumn has, it's just skinnier. The problem is the DataPropertyName is the name of the DataColumn the ColumnBoxExColumn needs to bind to. The DataSource of ComboBoxExColumn can be a DataTable and you can use DisplayMember and ValueMember BUT the Item type is DataRowView. While the Item type of the underlying data is String (it's the type of the DataColumn which the ComboBoxExColumn is bound to via DataPropertyName). That will make it not work (for ComboBoxExColumn), for ComboBoxColumn, it even throws exceptions (I tested it)...

Comment: My DataColumn is type of string or bool (standard type). If it is string (the values are only "Male" and "Female"), the ComboBoxExColumn should have DataSource as an Array of string like this: new string[]{"Male", "Female"}, it can't be a DataTable or any other complex data type like this: new [] { new { Gender = "Male"}, new {Gender = "Female"}} If that is OK, you can assign the DisplayMember to "Gender" but it's not. It requires the Item of the DataSource is type of string. If my DataColumn is type of bool, the DataSource should be: new bool[] {true, false}  ... You can test this easily.

Comment: What is the original data type of your 'gender' column in your data table? The data source of the combo box should be an array of objects with at least two properties. One (the ValueMember) holds the data which can be found in the gender column of the original data, and the other one (the DisplayMember) is the string (could be of any type though) which is to be shown on screen.

Comment: The original data type of my Gender column is bit/boolean, but I want to show the value as string. Your idea is OK for normal ComboBox (on form), but this is ComboBox in DataGridView (and so-called DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) and it works differently from the normal ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but I think you are heading in the wrong direction.

Let the DataGridView display how you would like to see and edit the data. Regarding your 'Gender' column, you should be able to setup your combobox column as follows:

Consider the following scenario: Your data table has a column 'Gender' which holds a 0 (unknown), 1(Male), 2(Female), 3(Other).

Here is a sample code which will define the lookup, creates sample data and populates the grid with data. The Gender will be displayed in english but stored as number.

```
    class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
    }
    class GenderLookup
    {
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    private void SetupGrid()
    {

    GenderLookup[] _lookups = new[]
        {
            new GenderLookup { Value = 0, Display = "unknown" }, 
            new GenderLookup { Value = 1, Display = "Male" },
            new GenderLookup { Value = 2, Display = "Female" }, 
            new GenderLookup { Value = 3, Display = "Other" }
        };

    Employee[] _employees = new[]
        {
            new Employee() { Gender = 1, Name = "James T. Kirk" }, 
            new Employee() { Gender = 2, Name = "Lt. Uhura" },
            new Employee() { Gender = 3, Name = "Data" }
        };
        GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView.DataSource = _employees;
        GridView.Columns.Add(
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() 
                { 
                    DataPropertyName = "Name" 
                }
            );

        GridView.Columns.Add(
            new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
                {
                    DataSource = _lookups,
                    DisplayMember = "Display",
                    ValueMember = "Value",
                    DataPropertyName = "Gender"
                }
            );
    }
```

So there is no need to 'parse' (or better: translate) the gender display name manually. The DataGridView creates a 'view' of your underlying data, which might be hard to read (as with the gender information in this case).

Comment: Have you tried this yet? As I said, the DataSource of the DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn can't be anything except an Array of string (in your code, it is an Array of anonymous type), because the underlying data Column is always type of string. This won't work, if I could use another kind of DataSource (not array of string) for my DataGridViewComboBoxExColumn, I would have my own solution. Thanks!

Comment: I went for the solution (I mentioned in my question) that adds a second column of Gender, this column is for displaying the value as string, the original column is for saving. I want to say more about normal ComboBox, it works with the idea of using DisplayMember and ValueMember because we can bind it's Properties freely to the underlying source, the most popular Properties I use are Text, SelectedIndex and SelectedValue. But for ComboBoxColumn in DataGridView, we even don't know what the Property of it is bound to the underlying source, I guess it is only the Text or something like that.

Comment: Hi. of course I tried it. If your gender column is bool, then simply replace the data type of the `Gender` and `Value` accordingly. Please bear in mind that in this case, only two types of gender are possible. Also, your assumption in the second comment are wrong. You should play with my example to understand the way this works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't make it work that way. If you want an example, I'm going to create a demo and post it here for you to test how it can work that way. Please wait...

Comment: It works. Call the `SetupGrid()` Method in your `Form_OnLoad` Event.

Comment: I have something wrong with my DataColumn type so it didn't work. In fact, I had tried the way you suggested before but the DataColumn type was not specified and it threw exception. Like this: myDataTable.Columns.Add("Gender")  =>> Won't work. I had to change it to: myDataTable.Columns.Add("Gender",typeof(bool)) and it works. However, that's just for test when the Columns are added manually. The columns in my main project are autogenerated via DataAdapter, the Column type may be the same to the type in SELECT query. I have to determine it, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: When creating such ComboBox-Columns, you usually know the datatype and have the correct lookup datasource. I always use an int for such values (i.e. qualitative properties like gender, job position etc.) and have the appropriate lookup table in the database. So I can easily create the combobox lookup by simply reading the lookup table and create nice looking reports using a join on the tables as well.

Comment: OK, I know how to use your code, don't worry too much about the order of code line, where to place it. I'm not such a newbie. I tested it and I even removed all the classes in your code and changed all the Arrays to DataTables (I want it that way). Now the problem of mine is my DataTable (source for my DataGridView) is filled by a DataAdapter and the (Gender) DataColumn type is not exactly what I thought. I'm using SQLite and it may be the problem. I'll test the type of column to do it accordingly. Thank you.